# Exact Term Search In Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, search

I'm trying to build a basic search where only the entire exact search term shows results. Currently it is showing results based on individual words.

Here's the code from the model:

```
def search
  find(:all, :conditions => ['term' == "%#{search}%"])
end
```

Sorry in advance. I'm very new to rails!

Thank you.

Comment: Try `find(:all, :conditions => ['term' == "#{search}"])`

Comment: What version of Rails do you use?

Comment: I'm using Rails 5.0.0

Comment: How does your controller look like? What is the name of the column that should match?

Comment: `before_action :set_index
        def set_index
     
            @b = Best.all
            if params[:search]
                @bests = @b.search(params[:search]).order(:cached_weighted_score => :desc)
                else
                @bests = @b.none
            end
      end`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the % from `"%#{search}%"` so it's `"#{search}"`.

`%` is a wildcard that matches every result containing the word. So `"%tea%"` for example would match tear, nestea, and steam, when that's not what you want.

This should yield an exact match:

`def search
  find(:all, :conditions => ['term' == "#{search}"])
end`

Comment: Thanks for this, but I'm still having trouble. For example if I search for a single letter "a" or example, I'm getting every listing with the letter 'a' in its name.

Comment: It looks like my def search isn't effecting anything for some reason. I've deleted it all out and I am still getting the same results..

Here's the code from the view:

`<%= form_tag root_path, :method => 'get', :class => "input-group-lg" do%>
 <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], remote: true, :class => "form-control", :placeholder => " Search for the best...", :autofocus => true % <%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil, remote: true, :class => "btn search-btn btn-lg" %>`

Answer (score 1):

Your code doesn't work for several reasons.

1. You do not pass any value to that method. Therefore `search` will always be `nil`.
2. The `['term' == "%#{search}%"]` condition doesn't make much sense because - as I said before - `search` is undefined and therefore the condition will is the same as `['term' == "%%"]`. The string `term` is not equal to `%%` therefore the whole condition is basically: `[false]`.
3. Rails 5.0 uses a different syntax for queries. The syntax you used is very old and doesn't work anymore.

I would do something like this:

```
# in your model
scope :search, -> (q) { 
  q.present? ? where("column_name LIKE :query", query: "%#{q}%") :none 
}

# in your controller
def set_index 
  @b = Best.search(params[:search]).order(:cached_weighted_score => :desc)
end
```